# Copy shape to blank canvas (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

blank_image = np.zeros((40,40,3), np.uint8)
blank_image.fill(255)

#cv2.imshow('i', blank_image)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

im = cv2.imread('img.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnt = contours[4]
cnts = cv2.drawContours(im,[cnt],0,(255,0,0), -1)

cv2.imshow('i', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)

for a in cnt:
    print(a) #this contour is a 3D numpy array
```

Source image:

[image: src]

I am using this code to:
1. create a white canvas of 40x40 pixels
2. found the contours of number (in this case 5) using Opencv function `findContours`.

[image: out1]

What I want to do is to copy this shape (please, not the bounding box or rectangle, the blue shape) into the canvas.

After some research I learned that an opencv image is just a numpy array. This array, theoretically, should be translated in the new image (my white canvas..) and then reconstruct the shape using the values inside the array. I am right ?

Someone know how to do that ? Creating a bounding box / rectangle around the numbers would, in some cases, result inaccurate. Please, don't give that as solution. I already did this process in atleast 3-4 different ways and the results are not satisfactory enough.

So, the desired output would be something like this..

[image: out2]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For contours image [image]

I think want something like [image]

---

For opened number such as `1`, `2`, `5` , it is easy to do: **Crop from the whole image, or draw on new image**. For closed number such as `0`, `6`, `8`, `9`, more steps are needed. Here is example for `5`, you will get [image].

---

**Details and description are in the code.**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.14 09:48:15 CST
# 2018.01.14 11:39:03 CST

import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('test.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]


## this contour is a 3D numpy array
cnt = contours[4]
res = cv2.drawContours(im,[cnt],0,(255,0,0), -1)
cv2.imwrite("contours.png", res)

## Method 1: crop the region
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
croped = res[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite("croped.png", croped)

## Method 2: draw on blank
# get the 0-indexed coords
offset = cnt.min(axis=0)
cnt = cnt - cnt.min(axis=0)
max_xy = cnt.max(axis=0) + 1
w,h = max_xy[0][0], max_xy[0][1]
# draw on blank
canvas = np.ones((h,w,3), np.uint8)*255
cv2.drawContours(canvas, [cnt], -1, (255,0,0), -1)
cv2.imwrite("canvas.png", canvas)
```

Comment: Yes! Finally! Do you confirm it crop, using the 2nd method, only the contour and after it paste it into the canvas ? It's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Also, is there a way to define a minArea of contour to detect ? For example, number 8 comes out filled with the color I selected in drawContours: [example](https://imgur.com/a/lpl1O)...