# cv2.drawContours() - unfill circles inside characters (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, contour

As suggested by @Silencer, I used the code he posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244328/copy-shape-to-blank-canvas-opencv-python/48246500#48246500) to draw contours around the numbers in my image. 
At some point, working with numbers like `0,6,8,9` I saw that their inside contours (the circles) are being filled as well.
How can I prevent this ? Is there a min/max area of action to set for cv2.drawContours() so I can exclude the inner area ?

[image: example]

I tried to pass `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` but with this parameter only the whole external area is considered.

The code is this (again, thanks Silencer. Was searching for this for months..):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('imgs\\2.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#contours.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

for i, cnts in enumerate(contours):
    ## this contour is a 3D numpy array
    cnt = contours[i]
    res = cv2.drawContours(im, [cnt], 0, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    cv2.imwrite("contours.png", res)
    '''
    ## Method 1: crop the region
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    croped = res[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("cnts\\croped{}.png".format(i), croped)
    '''
    ## Method 2: draw on blank
    # get the 0-indexed coords
    offset = cnt.min(axis=0)
    cnt = cnt - cnt.min(axis=0)
    max_xy = cnt.max(axis=0) + 1
    w, h = max_xy[0][0], max_xy[0][1]
    # draw on blank
    canvas = np.ones((h, w, 3), np.uint8) * 255
    cv2.drawContours(canvas, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1)

    #if h > 15 and w < 60:
    cv2.imwrite("cnts\\canvas{}.png".format(i), canvas)
```

The main image on which I am working..

[image: src]

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I implemented Fiver answer below and this is the result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png')
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img_v = img_hsv[:, :, 2]

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(~img_v, 127, 255, 0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    tmp_img = np.zeros(img_v.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    res = cv2.drawContours(tmp_img, [c], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

    tmp_img = np.bitwise_and(tmp_img, ~img_v)

    ret, inverted = cv2.threshold(tmp_img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    cnt = contours[i]

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cropped = inverted[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    cv2.imwrite("roi{}.png".format(i), cropped)
```

Comment: drawcontours last -1 is thickness, when negative it fills the inside, when positive it just draws the line. At least this happens in the last drawcontours... not in the first one

Comment: I used that, but with 1 it show me only the external contour. So I will have something [like this](https://imgur.com/a/UJ0y8), which is not the main goal..

Comment: oh I see, true, maybe you can draw twice, 1 like what you have and the second time the inner ones (look at the hierarchy) and draw them filled in white

Comment: Used different hierarchy but nothing seems to change at output level.

Comment: @Link To be honest, I tried use hierarchy, but failed. I just don't know how to use it... And an alternative is crop the region, then find small contours again, then draw the smaller in inversed color..

Comment: @Silencer I'll try now the alternative you think...If I am thinking right, it's just matter of minutes..

Comment: I am trying to use cv2.contourArea(cnt) to find the area of each contour and then exclude the ones below a certain value. By doing this, if he finds a circle in number 6 it will make all the image white, not only that specified contour.

Comment: I know where I was wrong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSh4C.png

Comment: @Silencer please could you share the solution / explain what you did ? For me, what I am trying actually doesn't work..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw the `char` without filled the closed inner regions:

> 1. find the contours on the threshed binary image with hierarchy.
> 2. find the outer contours that don't have inner objects (by flag hierarchy[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqSTd.png)).
> 3. for each outer contour:
>
>    3.1 fill it(maybe need check whether needed);
>
>    3.2 then iterate in it's inner children contours, fill then with other color(such as inversed color).
> 4. combine with the crop code, crop them.
> 5. maybe you need sort them, resplit them, normalize them.
> 6. maybe, now you can do ocr with the trained model.

---

FindContours, refill the inner closed regions.

[image]

Combine with this answer  [Copy shape to blank canvas (OpenCV, Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244328/copy-shape-to-blank-canvas-opencv-python/48246500#48246500), do more steps, maybe you can get this or better:

[image]

---

The core code to `refill` the inner closed regions is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.14 09:48:15 CST
# 2018.01.15 17:56:32 CST
# 2018.01.15 20:52:42 CST

import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img02.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## Threshold 
ret, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## FindContours
cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]

canvas = np.zeros_like(img)
n = len(cnts)
hiers = hiers[0]

for i in range(n):
    if hiers[i][3] != -1:
        ## If is inside, the continue 
        continue
    ## draw 
    cv2.drawContours(canvas, cnts, i,  (0,255,0), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    ## Find all inner contours and draw 
    ch = hiers[i][2]
    while ch!=-1:
        print(" {:02} {}".format(ch, hiers[ch]))
        cv2.drawContours(canvas, cnts, ch, (255,0,255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        ch = hiers[ch][0]

cv2.imwrite("001_res.png", canvas)
```

Run this code with this image:

[image]

You will get:

[image]

---

Of course, this is for two hierarchies. I haven't test for more than two. You who need can do test by yourself.

---

Update:

Notice in different OpenCVs, the `cv2.findContours` return different values. To keep code executable, we can just get the last two returned values use: cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(...)[-2:]

In OpenCV 3.4:

[image]

In OpenCV 4.0:

[image]

---

Comment: Still trying to solve this puzzle, I am begin to think I am missing something at this point.. LOL

Comment: BIG improvement: I achieved to save all the numbers which have contours inside (0,6,8,9) right. Still didn't find a way to save the "normal" chars...

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a mask from your threshold step, you can also use it to `bitwise_and` against the drawn contour:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('drawn_chars.png')
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img_v = img_hsv[:, :, 2]

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(~img_v, 127, 255, 0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    thresh, 
    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
)

for c in contours:
    tmp_img = np.zeros(img_v.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(tmp_img, [c], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

    tmp_img = np.bitwise_and(tmp_img, ~img_v)

    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 2))
    plt.imshow(tmp_img, cmap='gray')
```

I've inverted the image so the contours are white and I left out the cropping as you already solved that. Here is the result on one of the "O" characters:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll try as soon as possible.

Comment: What does `~img_v` mean ?

Comment: The `~` is the complement operator, it flips the bits, and in doing so inverts the grayscale image...255 become 0, 254 becomes 1, etc. It comes in quite handy at times. It isn't strictly necessary as you could just threshold from 0 to 127.

Answer (score 1):

Full code...

This will not sort the images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('imgs\\1.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## Threshold
ret, threshed = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## FindContours
image, cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

canvas = np.zeros_like(im)
n = len(cnts)
hiers = hiers[0]

for i, imgs in enumerate(cnts):

    cnt = cnts[i]
    res = cv2.drawContours(im, [cnt], 0, (0, 0, 0), -1)

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    croped = res[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    if h > 10:
        cv2.imwrite("out\\croped{}.png".format(i), croped)
        cv2.imshow('i', croped)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

for i, value in enumerate(cnts):

    ## this contour is a 3D numpy array
    cnt = cnts[i]
    res = cv2.drawContours(im, [cnt], 0, (0, 0, 0), -1)
    # cv2.imwrite("out\\contours{}.png".format(i), res)

    ## Find all inner contours and draw
    ch = hiers[i][2]
    while ch != -1:
        print(" {:02} {}".format(ch, hiers[ch]))
        res1 = cv2.drawContours(im, cnts, ch, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        ch = hiers[ch][0]

        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        croped = res[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        if h > 10:
            cv2.imwrite("out\\croped{}.png".format(i), croped)
```

Any correction is accepted.

Comment: In fact, here there is a problem. The second part is cropping instead of contouring. Which is wrong, for now..

Comment: @Silencer What I am doing wrong ? By putting the code which copy the contours into canvas instead of the cropping one, it still get me the inner contour blacked...

Answer (score 1):

This will do definetively the job...

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

retval, thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

medianFiltered = cv2.medianBlur(thresholded, 3)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(medianFiltered, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contour_list = []
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > 80:
        contour_list.append(contour)

numbers = cv2.drawContours(img, contour_list, -1, (0, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('i', numbers)
cv2.waitKey(0)

sorted_ctrs = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, cnts in enumerate(contours):

    cnt = contours[i]

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    croped = numbers[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    h, w = croped.shape[:2]
    print(h, w)

    if h > 15:
        cv2.imwrite("croped{}.png".format(i), croped)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is conceptually similar to Fivers answer, just that bitwise_and occurs outside the for loop and perhaps is better in terms of performance. Source code is in C++ for those looking for C++ answer for this problem.

```
int thWin = 3;
int thOffset = 1;
cv::adaptiveThreshold(image, th, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV, thWin, thOffset);

int minMoveCharCtrArea = 140;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(th.clone(), contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cv::Mat filtImg = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1 );

for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); ++i) {
    int ctrArea = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
    if (ctrArea > minMoveCharCtrArea) {
        cv::drawContours(filtImg, contours, i, 255, -1);
    }
}
cv::bitwise_and(th, filtImg, filtImg);
```

Remember to clone the image (for python it should be copy) when passing source image argument to findContours, since findContours modifies the original image. I reckon later versions of opencv (perhaps opencv3 +) don't require cloning.